# ios - stop scroll when reach to expected contentOffset

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, pull

The image https://www.dropbox.com/s/e7b189mzl168efk/scrollview.png is my scrollview and 4views.
What I want is when I pulldown the scrollView it display the views base on the offset.
And I want to stop the scroll when it reach to end view. Currently it still continue to scroll.

its like

```
if(scrollView.contentOffset.y == -155)
```

then scroll will not continue to scroll but i can still scroll back to the bottom to highlight the view3 or until view1. Please refer on the image.

example code is very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if I understand the question, but to stop a scrolling scroll view you can do the following in the delegate of the scroll view:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y <= -155.0) {
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -155.0) animated:NO];
    }
}
```

And if you want to scroll to a specific view you can do the same:

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, targetView.frame.origin.y) animated:YES];
```

Comment: You are almost right, for the bottom part change "<=" into ">="

Comment: if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < -155.0) { [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -155.0) animated:NO]; } else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > 154.0) { [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 154.0) animated:NO]; }

Comment: anyone please also help me to get out from this issue